# Data Augmentation CIFAR-10 reduces CNN model accuracy

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, conv-neural-network

I have a [Conv-6](https://github.com/arjun-majumdar/Lottery_Ticket_Hypothesis-TensorFlow_2/blob/master/Data_Augmentation_Conv6_CIFAR10_Example.ipynb) CNN for CIFAR-10 where I am using Python3, TensorFlow2.0 based data augmentations as follows:

```
# Example of using 'tf.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator class's - flow(x, y)':

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    # featurewise_center=True,
    # featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range = 90,
    width_shift_range = 0.1,
    height_shift_range = 0.1,
    horizontal_flip = True
)
```

But using this data augmentation technique reduces the accuracy to 66.43%. As opposed to this, when I train the same model without any data augmentations, the accuracy is 79.22%.

What's going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You have to understand the effect of each of those augmentations that you specify. For example - do all the classes remain the same after you apply horizontal flip or rotate your image by 90 degrees.

Comment: @AdityaMishra good point, I have reduced the image distortion by reducing rotation_range from 90 to 20 and the validation accuracy with augmentation is about 76% as opposed to 79% without augmentation. Remaining parameters in ImageGenerator() are same.

Answer (score 0):

acc. to my knowledge augmentation is helpful when your model is kind of over fitting and u need to generalize ur model and make more powerfull. augmentation wont help if your model isn't giving much accuracy.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32244434)